# Separated frontend with backbone.js and node.js backend token

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, backbone.js

I have separated projects,

Server side node.js with express to serve restful api but returning JSON instead html. All the examples in internet are returning html with ejs.

Frontend is and independent application with backbone and socket.io.

I want to do a login and registration page and I did it with passport.js on the server side, but I have not idea of how to send the token to the frontend and store it there to send It on every request to the server. If the user is out of session then the login page, ,must be shown.

I want a way compatible with oauth 2.0 for multiple authentication strategies.

Sorry for my English and I have a lot of dudes and I don't understand all the concepts.

Comment: All the routing is made by the backbone router instead of routing the pages with the server in express.

Comment: *"All the examples in internet are returning html with ejs."* uhm... the restful api examples certainly don't all return html.

Comment: *"I want to do a login and registration page and I did it with passport.js on the server side, but I have not idea of how to send the token to the frontend and store it there to send It on every request to the server. If the user is out of session then the login page, ,must be shown."* you have to build that functionality yourself if the framework you are using doesn't do it for you. Simply have a login page that interacts with the api, and then stores the token as a cookie to be used with future requests.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you have is an API and a client, and you need two things:

- The client to be able to open a session on the API.
- The client to be able to embed its session credentials in every request so that the API knows who is doing the query.

### First Step

For opening the session, you have figured it out: you want your API to be an Oauth **Client**.

So when a user wants to log in, your client will redirect it to http://api.yourserver.com/login/google which will redirect to google, which will redirect again to your API with a token that allow your API to access Google's API (hence, know who your user is).

This token cannot be used to authenticate against your API. Its only goal is to allow your API to act on the user's behalf on google services.

### Second Step

Then you need to decide how will your client authenticate against your API. You can choose to use a cookie which almost everyone do (it's the sane default for express sessions).

Or, if your API is consumed by many different clients, and you don't have control over those clients, you can choose to implement an Oauth **Server** to protect your API.

The clients will then authenticate against your API using a "Bearer Token" (it's an HTTP header).